# How to initialize a dynamic class that has a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following class:

```
public class CustomItem
{
    //....
}
```

and there are multiple classes which accept `CustomClass` in their constructor methods. e.g:

```
public class FirstClass
{
   public FirstClass(CustomItem customItem) { }
}
```

I am trying to create a generic method which accepts a dynamic class and initialize it. Something like this:

```
public List<T> MyTestMethod<T>(CustomItem myCustomItem) where T : class, new()
{
   List<T> list = new List<T>();
   foreach(CustomItem myCustomItem in listOfCustomItems)
   {
      T instance = new T(myCustomItem);
      list.Add(T);
   }
   return list;
}
```

So, that it can be used like:

```
List<FirstClass> List1 = MyTestMethod<FirstClass>(customItem);
List<SecondClass> List2 = MyTestMethod<SecondClass>(customItem);
```

The syntax to instantiate `T` in `MyTestMethod` is incorrect.
Is what I'm trying to do, possible?

Comment: Why don't you allow a `Func<CustomItem, T>` to be passed in lieu of a `new` constraint? That way callers could create instances as they please. (It would also make `MyTestMethod` effectively obsolete, as you could just have a `.Select(...).ToList()` chain.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Could you pls help me with sample code.

Comment: `listOfCustomItems.Select(c => new FirstClass(c)).ToList()`. There you go, I just obsoleted `MyTestMethod` entirely. But if it's more complicated than that, `MyTestMethod` could be `MyTestMethod<T>(Func<CustomItem, T> itemCreator) { ... foreach (var c in listOfCustomItems) { T t = itemCreator(c); ... } }`. If you insist on keeping it as constructors, and you don't want to pass these explicitly, you can do things with reflection, but this needs care and attention to optimize. (Notably, `Activator.CreateInstance`, while convenient, is *ungodly* slow compared to direct calls.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `Activator` class to create an instance with arguments:

```cs
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args: myCustomItem);
```

In your situation:

```cs
public List<T> MyTestMethod<T>(CustomItem myCustomItem) where T : class
{
   List<T> list = new List<T>();
   foreach(CustomItem myCustomItem in listOfCustomItems)
   {
      T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args: myCustomItem);
      list.Add(instance);
   }
   return list;
}
```

Comment: Notice: the `new()` constraint isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
T instance =  (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), myCustomItem);
```

sorry, correct answer was given 10 seconds before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829165/5281555 :)